# Converting Python loop to PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell

I'm trying to convert a Python script to PowerShell and I'm getting hung up understanding what's going on in a loop in the Python script. Here is an example of the Python script.

```
import time

def obfuscateApiKey () :
    seed = 'f1avad34567a'
    now = str(long(time.time() * 1000))
    n = now[-6:]
    r = str(int(n) >> 1).zfill(6)
    key = ""
    for i in range(0, len(n), 1):
        key += seed[int(n[i])]
    for j in range(0, len(r), 1):
        key += seed[int(r[j])+2]

    print "Timestamp:%s     Key:%s" % (now, key)

obfuscateApiKey()
```

This is what I've come up with so far for the PowerShell conversion but I don't have any Python experience and have hit a wall understanding what's taking place in the loops.

```
$seed = 'f1avad34567a'
$Now = ([int](get-date -UFormat %s) *1000).ToString()
$n = $now.Substring( [math]::Max( 0, $now.Length – 6 ) )
$r = $n -shr 1
$key = @()
```

Anybody have tips on how to do this part in PowerShell?

```
for i in range(0, len(n), 1):
    key += seed[int(n[i])]
for j in range(0, len(r), 1):
    key += seed[int(r[j])+2]
```

Comment: Just as a side note, `range(0, len(n), 1)` is just `range(len(n))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this obfuscate a key? It takes no parameters and depends on the current time, so it appears non-reversible and non-repeatable. If the only thing it is is 'verifiable' - i.e. someone else can read the printed timestamp, know the seed, and check the generated key. If that's true, it's very tempting to say run it once and just replace the function with the fixed print statement `'Timestamp:1503715652844     Key:3da5aada53aa'` which will be forever valid.

Original:

```
def obfuscateApiKey():
    seed = 'f1avad34567a'               # string
    now = str(long(time.time() * 1000)) # current timestamp with
                                        #   milliseconds rolled in, as string
    n = now[-6:]                        # last 6 chars
    r = str(int(n) >> 1).zfill(6)       # right bit shift 1 and
                                        #   left pad to len 6 with zeros

    key = ""                            # empty string

    for i in range(0, len(n), 1):       # 0,1,2,3,4,5 (because n is len 6)
        key += seed[int(n[i])]          # string index in n, lookup in seed

    for j in range(0, len(r), 1):       # 0,1,2,3,4,5 again (?), r is len 6
        key += seed[int(r[j])+2]        # string index in r, lookup in seed

    print "Timestamp:%s     Key:%s" % (now, key)    # print
```

PowerShell:

```
$seed = 'f1avad34567a'

# Bit of a mess, to handle get-date returning local time
# but Unix timestamps needing to be in UTC timezone
$now = [string][math]::Floor([double](Get-Date -Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s) * 1000)

# Your substring line
$n = $now.Substring([math]::Max(0, $now.Length–6))

# Your shift-right, but $n was a string, so convert to [int]
# and PadLeft is the equivalent of zfill
$r = "$([int]$n -shr 1)".PadLeft(6, '0')

# string concatenation works in PS, for small uses it's fine.
$key = ''

# The loops and indexing almost translate. I've made them fixed
# ranges because it seems the lengths of the strings are fixed.
# The casting is awkward, but the result of looking up a character
# from a string is type [char] and they cast to int as the 
# ascii/unicode codepoint value, not the numeric value of the content.
0..5 | ForEach-Object {
    $key += $seed[[int][string]$n[$_]]
}

0..5 | ForEach-Object {
    $key += $seed[[int][string]$r[$_]+2]
}

'Timestamp:{0}    Key:{1}' -f $now, $key
```

Comment: This works great and I really appreciate all the detail and explanation. When the post is submitted, it contains the timestamp and key. They know the seed. If the timestamp is more than two hours old, it won't be accepted.

I wasn't quite sure about the use of `zfill`. If `n` is taking the last 6 characters from `now`, wouldn't the original string always be returned since the width in `zfill` is 6?